# How to create line buffer bounded by polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

I need to create a buffer around the lines, but so that it doesn't go outside the polygon. Simply creating a buffer around the lines is not a problem, ArcGIS has such a tool, but I did not find how to limit this buffer to a polygon. I will attach a picture so that it is clear what I mean. How can this be implemented?

[image]

Comment: Use union tool, then select and dissolve.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't use the union tool. A line object is a linear object, and a boundary is a polygon.

Comment: convert the line boundary into a polygon first.